# Modules Not Appearing on Pages

Tags: html, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-module

My company likes to apply custom HTML modules to our current website, but we've lately run into issues where the modules do not appear on the front end, even when going through the correct processes to allow it to.

- Create article
- Create Menu Item
- Attach article to menu item
- In Module Manager, apply to menu item
- Get mad at Joomla after the module does not appear on the front end of the site

The curious thing is, after trying to apply modules for months, I go on yesterday and create another new article and menu item, CREATE a new module and it appears fine. Even curiouser is that some modules do appear on pages, but those same modules will not appear on a different menu/article item. I've researched the web and found similar occurrences of this happening and tried their strategies of fixing this error, but NONE of them have worked. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: module position is correct? maybe the menu item has a different template where the current module position is not available.

Comment: the module position is set to onethird. The menu items are all set with the "Use Default" option under template style, which all pages are set as. I did think that and tried switching the template of the menu items, but that still did not work.

Comment: Okay, so the only way I've been able to fix this problem is to copy the page into a new article and redo the entire process again, which seems to work.

Comment: @Tash Pemhiwa, if you're going to remove the Joomla version from the question, please insert it in the actual question, as an *old* version could be the cause of someone's issue ;)

Comment: Yeah, not sure why the version was taken out as it is necessary to answer my question.

Comment: one question: if you set your module assignment to "ON ALL PAGES", does it actually show up site-wide?

Comment: @Lodder, there is a tag for Joomla 2.5. Does that not make it clear which version it is for?

Comment: @Grafi no. It is the same thing. Appears on some pages but not all. As stated in my third comment, the ONLY solution I seem to have found is doing the entire process a second time. Article creation>Menu Creation>Assign module.